# Android WIFI Socket Name?

Tags: android, wifi

I am developing one Android application which communicate with Wifi network. I want to know the name of the wifi socket in Android Device. i searched in google but nothing help me. I heard android device used RFCOMM socket for Bluetooth communication. Is RFCOMM socket used for Wifi communication?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be some help:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html

Cheers,

Darren

Comment: Its explain Wifi API but i need name of the socket.

Comment: Is it possible to get the name of the socket through the methods that the API exposes?